# Can i exclude certain page templates for a specific role?

Tags: templates, hooks, permissions

Let's say i have two types of templates available when making a Page. "Default template" and "Intermediate template".

I have a role called "editor", and i do not want the editor to access the "Intermediate template".

Is this possible (with a hook) ?

Comment: Do you need to hide a template from the page editor screen back end so that the user only have the one option to choose from when he creates a new page? Please answer this in the form of an [edit] to your question

Comment: Good point @PieterGoosen, I've answered the question maybe incorrectly. Ooops, no, I was right, my answer was accepted.

Comment: @cybmeta hahaha, great. Question is a bit ambiguous. Read your answer and the question, bit confusing :-). Enjoy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to change the template used, you can use the `template_include` filter (change "itermediate-template.php" and "page.php" with correct file names of your template files):

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'cyb_exclude_template_for_editors', 99 );
function cyb_exclude_template_for_editors( $template ) {

    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if( in_array( "editor", (array) $user->roles ) && is_page_template( "itermediate-template.php" ) ) {
        $new_template = locate_template( array( 'page.php' ) );
        if ( '' != $new_template ) {
            return $new_template ;
        }
    }

    return $template;
}
```

If you need to redirect the user to another page you can use `template_redirect` filter:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'cyb_redirect_editors_from_page_template' );
function cyb_redirect_editors_from_page_template() {

    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if( in_array( "editor", (array) $user->roles ) && is_page_template( "itermediate-template.php" ) ) {
        //Redirect to home, change to fit your needs
        wp_redirect( home_url() );
        exit();
    }

}
```